# How to enable iframe scrollbar on iOS safari

Tags: ios, safari, scrollbar

I am trying to implement facebook's live stream plugin on my website. I see that there is a scrollbar on pc and mac browsers, but not on iphone or ipad safari. I think it is because iphone and ipad treat scrollbar differently since they are both touch based devices. So I expect to scroll iframe with two fingers, but it does not work either.

Here is sample page (used a different src url) http://para.qacode.com/test.php

How do I enable two finger scrolling or normal scrollbar on ios safari?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS versions prior to 5, you can scroll iframes on iPad/iPhone using two fingers, but this is a bit of a hidden feature and most people don't know about it. I'm not sure why tow-finger scrolling isn't working for your iframe - perhaps there is some JavaScript intercepting the touch event?

On iOS 5 this has been fixed and scrolling works as expected for iframes with one finger.

If you need to scroll a sub-region of the page on iOS 4 and earlier, the best bet is to use a library such as iScroll that implements scrolling with JavaScript touch-event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these styles to the parent container:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
overflow:auto;
```